# How to pass data from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page, in that i am showing the DB table records like below,
where resultset_values--this object contain all ResultSet value that I am passing from servlet.

```
    <%Iterator itr;%>
    <% ArrayList data= 
    (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("resultset_values");                        
    for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
     {
    %>

    <tr>
     <td width="119"><a href="files.jsp"><%= itr.next()%></a></td>
     <td width="168"

    ><%=itr.next()%></td>
    <td width="200"><%=itr.next()%></td>            
    </tr>
    <%}%>
```

On iteration it is printing all values in tabular format. First `<%= itr.next()%>` will print the table id.I am giving a link to another jsp page(files.jsp) on click of that id.
now how can i send this id (what i have clicked) to files.jsp. I was trying to set the value through request and session (`request.setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()`)but I didnt
get that id getting error as `itr.next()` is `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understood from your question.

    itr.next() prints the id  and you have to pass this id to files.jsp when the user click on the link.
If this is what you want do the following

```
<a href = "files.jsp?id=<%=itr.next().toString()%>" >  <%= itr.next()%>  </a>
```

In files.jsp do the following.

    request.getParameter("id");

Hope this helps you..

Comment: already i have done this but it is giving error java.util.NoSuchElementException "at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)"